# Como ativar o autofocus com jquery numa div?

Tags: jquery

Como ativar o autofocus com jquery numa div? Quero fazer um autofocus em um input assim que o usuário fizer  tal ação...

Comment: O autofoco seria para dar foco ao carregar a página. Se é após uma ação, basta você dar o foco no campo fazendo [`$("seu campo").focus()`](https://api.jquery.com/focus/)

Comment: QUE DELICIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA VALEUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU

Comment: Como complemento ao que já foi respondido pelo @AndersonCarlosWoss e ainda que não focando a tag, pode fazer o mesmo só com html utilizando o atributo `autofocus`, que irá funcionar como o focus quando abre a página.

Answer (score 6):

Basta você utilizar a função [`focus`](https://api.jquery.com/focus/) do jQuery quando você deseja dar o foco no campo. Por exemplo, dar o foco em um campo de texto ao clicar no botão:

```js
$(() => {
  $("#btn").on("click", event => {
    $("#nome").focus();
    console.log("O campo está em foco.");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="nome" type="text">
<button id="btn">Foco</button>
```